# Put ImageView exactly over VideoView

Tags: android, imageview, android-videoview

I need to put a ImageView exactly over a VideoView.
When I use this code in a RelativLayout

```
<VideoView
     android:id="@+id/videoView1"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/imageView1"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
```

the VideoView is shown on the top, the ImageView is centered vertically.
What can be done to also center the ImageView, that both Views are at the same position and have the same size, when a video and a picture with the same resolution are displayed?

Comment: read about a FrameLayout

Comment: @pskink That's the easy answer to my question!! I just replaced every RelativeLayout with FrameLayout and it worked very well.

Comment: @pskink you can post this as answer to let everybody see how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just replaced my RelativLayout with an FrameLayout and everything did well.

Comment: Hello @user2737037, am asking on this question, me too i placed an ImageView on Top of a videoView , but both of them are loaded in a RecyclerView, but what i want is a logic when the Image is the one present the VideoView is not seen and viceversa , please do you have any clue on that

Answer (score 1):

**Place first videoview then imageview in framelayout, if you are still facing problem there might be..**

> videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true) set by you, so make it false or remove
>   it.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer seems to be here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html
you need to use the ids of the elements you are trying align with.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp" >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/reminder" />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/dates"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/name"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/times" />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@id/times"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/name"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/times"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/done" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Your example should be something like this ,I have not been able to test it yet .

```
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/imageView1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<VideoView
     android:id="@+id/videoView1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@id/imageView1"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
```